# How to get Unity application using SQLite (SimpleSQL) working on Epson Moverio BT-300?

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, unity-game-engine, epson

I am developing an AR application in Unity and we are using the SimpleSQL SQLite plugin for our local database.

This is all working well when building for windows and also when building for ODG R7 AR glasses or my Samsung Galaxy S7 (both Android OS although the ODG is not an Android certified device). But when I install and run the APK on the Moverio BT-300; the application loads but cannot find the DB. For instance the buttons and images which normally load from the DB do not load. The images appear as white squares instead.

My first hunch was that it was something to do with the application.persistentdatapath and that this may somehow be different on the Moverio. Although I'm not entirely sure where SimpleSQL stores its data. I know that it makes a copy of the database that I have created at runtime but I don't know where that is stored. I assume that something on the Moverio headset is blocking the apps access to the required folder where the SimpleSQL SQLite DB is stored.

I have contacted Epson support in relation to this numerous times now and had no response.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: if you can attach adb to the moverio that would greatly help you in figuring out where it tries to load the db from.

Comment: I have attached adb but my inexperience is a disadvantage here. There appears to be a lot of commands. I managed to display connected device list which shows the Moverio. I might add that in my app I tried to display the application.persistentDataPath and it showed it but I cannot find this location when I browse the folders from my PC via USB.

Comment: "adb logcat"   launch your app and look for errors. you can filter only the unity output easily with -s "Unity" , but you might want the other output too. theres a lot of junk in that log though but just launch your app and stop the output and have a look around.

try "adb shell" to look better than using windows folders.  or the debug helper tool in android studio which you can use to browse the folders.

your applications persistentpath might not be even visible through the usb/media player storage interface. if that was how you were doing it before to copy the sqlite over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution was to use SQLite4Unity3d

https://github.com/codecoding/SQLite4Unity3d

It works on all our devices.